# "/bin/sh: [/bin/sh,: not found" response when spining up kilna/liquibase-postgres

Tags: docker, liquibase

[image]when spinning up docker image [kilna/liquibase-postgres], we are getting:

```
"/bin/sh: [/bin/sh,: not found"
```

As a response in the container log and the container is exiting abruptly.

Additional Note: We are using macOS Catalina and default bash is zsh.

Any pointers appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How are you running the container? Command line? Compose file? Please show either.

Comment: Please edit the question to include an [mcve], including all relevant source code required to reproduce the issue.  Speculating, you can hit this error with a Dockerfile `CMD` line that doesn't have the correct form of quotes (exactly `"` ASCII straight double quotes).

Comment: please add your dockerfile or docker-compose or at least your imperative command which you used to spin up the docker container

Comment: This might help you https://github.com/kilna/liquibase-postgres-docker

Answer (score 2):

The command given in the Dockerfile is incorrect.

```
"Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "['/bin/sh', '-i']"
            ],
```

It has nested `/bin/sh`. Argument for the flag `-c` should be a single string. It can not be an array.

So, it gives `docker run kilna /bin/sh: [/bin/sh,: not found` error.

Change the `CMD` as `CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/sh -i"]`, build and run.

```
$ docker run -it kilna
/ #
```

Comment: Correct as far as it goes, though I'm a little unclear on _why_ the OP would nest the inner `sh` inside an outer one, instead of just running `CMD ["/bin/sh", "-i"]`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy argument `-i` creates new an interactive shell. So, we need to specify either `/bin/sh -i` or `sh -i`. We can not execute it directly on the running shell.

Comment: @hariK, I couldn't find a Cmd in the dockerfile of kilna/liquibase-postgres, is this in a different dockerfile?

Comment: @ragavravi It's coming from the base image [liquibase](https://github.com/kilna/liquibase-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile#L33)

Comment: @hariK what does the "-c" stands for?  and i checked the base image in liquibase has CMD ["/bin/sh", "-i"].